# Why do I get a NPE when setting the value of a progressbar?

Tags: java, download, nullpointerexception

I have a program that right now calls another class to handle downloads. This is the main code that gets the download percentage and sets the progress bar value and a label to it.

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
        {
            downloaded += count;
            downloadedPerc = (downloaded/getModPackSize())*100;
            System.out.println(downloadedPerc);
            progressBar.setValue(downloadedPerc);
            label.setText(downloadedPerc + "%");
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

I get a NullPointerException on progressBar.setValue(downloadedPerc+1); line, and I have no idea why, why could it be?

Comment: Where do you define and set `progressBar`? It could be null.

Comment: Check if progressBar is null.

Comment: Because either progressBar or downloadedPerc is null. If downloadedPerc is primitive type (`float` ot `double`, beginning with small letter) then progressBar must be null. maybe you should have posted more code than this little fragment.

Comment: @zyngawow Please, accept and answer if the problem is solved :)

Comment: Now I get on the console 0 in an infinite loop, and I also dont know why

Comment: Because (count = in.read(data, 0, 1024))  is never -1. Check the loop exit clause. If you cannot fix it, open another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `progressBar` is `null` as it hasn't been set at this point, or the value you have set is hidden by a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `progressBar` variable is `null`, make sure you are assigning a value to this variable earlier in the code. You can verify that this is the problem by doing a little debugging.